# Using controller as syntax only updates one of the scopes

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-controlleras

I'm a bit confused when it comes to the `controller as` syntax as I've never worked with it before. I'd like to know the correct way to fix this. Haven't been able to find a similar problem when searching.

I have a menu and a button which toggles the menu. The menu has its own scope and the button has another, as they live in two separate files and containers.

When I click the button it only updates the `nav.isActive` within the button scope. I created a service for storing the state, which I shouldn't have to do when I think about it.. Should I? Because the only way to watch if that value changes is with a watcher, which would require me to use `$scope` since `this` doesn't have the `$watch` function, however, I'd like to avoid this as much as I can as it will affect performance which is important in this project.

What is the correct way of updating a "scope" variable from another "scope" when using the `controller as` syntax?

Controller:

```
nav.controller('NavCtrl', ['navState', function(navState) {

  var nav = this;

  nav.menu = [
    {icon: 'color_lens', href: ''},
    {icon: 'color_lens', href: 'about'},
    {icon: 'color_lens', href: 'contact'},
    {icon: 'color_lens', href: 'logout'},
    {icon: 'color_lens', href: 'faq'}
  ];

  nav.toggleMenu = function() {
    nav.isActive = navState.checkState();
  }

}]);
```

The service for passing the value from one scope to the other:

```
nav.service('navState', [function() {

  var isActive = false;

  this.checkState = function() {

    isActive = !isActive;

    return !isActive;
  }
}]);
```

The menu markup (menu.html):

```
<nav class="si-wrapper si-dark" ng-controller="NavCtrl as nav" ng-class="{active: nav.isActive}">
  <ul class="si-list">
    <li class="si-item" ng-repeat="item in nav.menu">
      <a href="#/{{item.href}}">
        <div class="si-inner-item">
          <i class="material-icons md-36" ng-bind="item.icon"></i>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <h1>{{nav.isActive}}</h1> <!-- This doesn't change -->
</nav>
```

The button which toggles the menu (header.html):

```
<div ng-controller="NavCtrl as nav">
  <button ng-click="nav.toggleMenu()">Toggle</button>
  <span>{{nav.isActive}}</span> <!-- This updates however -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `nav.isActive` is not set for one of the controllers. Basically whenever you use `ng-controller` a new controller (and `$scope`) is created. So for each of your controllers, `$scope.isActive` needs to be set for the related view to reference it.

In your posted code, `isActive` is only set when `toggleMenu()` is run, which happens only in header.html.

In order to get your code to work, simply set `isActive` on controller load. For example:

```
nav.controller('NavCtrl', ['navState', function(navState) {
    // put isActive on the scope on controller load
    this.activeState = navState.getState();

    nav.toggleMenu = function() {
        navState.toggleState();
    };
}]);
```

You need to make your service better by separating state access and state manipulation. Also wrapping it in a container object will ensure you won't have any scope hierarchy issues.

```
nav.service('navState', [function() {

    var state = {
        isActive: false
    };

    this.toggleState = function() {
        state.isActive = !state.isActive;
    };

    this.getState = function(){
        return state;
    };
}]);
```

Then you need to use `activeState.isActive' inside your view.

Now you will have a service with a shareable state, and two controllers that both reference the same service on load. Then inside your menu view, when you toggle the state, both controllers scopes are updated.

Comment: Looked promising but still get the same issue as before :/

Comment: Nevermind, must've done something wrong. Seems to be working. Although I'm confused as to why activeState has to be bound to the state object in the controller and not state.isActive?

Comment: It is good practice to use a wrapping object to avoid scope hierarchy issues. Imagine doing this `$scope.isActive = false;` in one of your controllers. This would override the service state reference, so isActive would no longer be a reference to the service. By wrapping it and doing `$scope.state.isActive = false;` you preserve the reference.

Answer (score 0):

From the angularjs docs:

> When a Controller is attached to the DOM via the ng-controller directive, Angular will instantiate a new Controller object, using the specified Controller's constructor function. A new child scope will be created and made available as an injectable parameter to the Controller's constructor function as $scope.

Additionally, the ng-controller directive has a scope that inherits from its parent scope. So,  you can also define the shared data in the parent. It will be accessible on the 'NavCtrl' scope. But since you want to use the controller as synax one way would be to share the data with a help of a service.

However, I don't like the approach with the 'ng-controller' directive. The other solution is to replace it with a hierarchy of directives where the child directives will require the parent one. Also use 'controllerAs' property there.